# Could not load compiled classes for initialization script from cache

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build

So i ran a java program in IntelliJ using Gradle for 2 hours and then my computer (which has Windows as its OS) didn't work correctly so I had to restart it. But then this problem occurred when building my Gradle Project, where it told me that it "Could not load compiled classes for initialization script from cache".

Answer (score 3):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552) from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75261509/3)

> The solution is really simple but it took me a long long time to figure it out so I wanted to share it with anyone who might also stumble across this problem (I also haven't seen a simple solution elsewhere).
>
> Step 1: Open the Explorer and go to "C:/Users/username/.gradle/caches" (if you don't see the .gradle folder in your file explorer you have either moved it to a different directory or you have to enable the ability to view hidden folders in your file explorer: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5 , I don't mean the .gradle folder inside your IntelliJ project but the Gradle user home directory which you can find in IntelliJ by clicking "File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle")
>
> Step 2: delete everything inside the caches folder (in other words, clear the Gradle cache)
>
> Step 3: start IntelliJ and rebuild your Project with gradle
>
> I did that and then my gradle Build worked again perfectly and I could run my code again. I hope it helps :)!