# How to Fix "Unable to load class 'ijmapper_1rieokv8rhb4jgn5hwsfn8yt8'" on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am actually a beginer at Android Studio. I am faciing this issue from a while whenever I try to open the Android Studio and any app project. The Gradle Build is failed with error showing:

`Unable to load class 'ijmapper_1rieokv8rhb4jgn5hwsfn8yt8'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.`

Even if I open a clean new project, still the same issue. Can anyone please help me?

I have attached the screenshot of the error.
[image: screenshot of the error]

I tried updating both the Java JRE and Android Studio. Still the same issue. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75263262

This also happened to me. So it appears some files in  "C:/Users/username/.gradle/caches" are locked by some other Java process, and that is preventing gradle from sync. If you find yourself that you cannot delete some files, that implies that those are locked by some other process

How to find which one check https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows

In my case it was OpenJDK process I had to kill in task managed.
After that I deleted gradle all gradle cache files, re-run AS, and evrything was working

Answer (score 0):

This is not IDE problem. it is system problem your system locked Gradle file located in "C:/Users/username/.gradle" remember file in folder name is ".gradle" that the cause of this error "ijmapper_1rieokv8rhb4jgn5hwsfn8yt8" and also if you facing issue with Maven you need to delete .m2 files in this location "C:/Users/username/.m2".

> Simple Delete .gradle folder file then your IDE redownloads Gradle fresh files
>
> If you facing this issue with Maven then delete .m2 folder files in your username folder

I also facing this issue with intellij IDEA with java project using gradle "ijMapper1_1dqxsnlqnuee3gw32ntn4nbzo" but this post help me to solve this issue. i hope my answer helpful for other peoples.